# least squares linear classifier - three classes matlab example

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition, least-squares

I am trying to understand how to implement a least square linear classifier for my dataset. The issue is that I have 3 classes and I am not sure how to get this done...

Here is a try. This works for 2 classes however I am suspecting that something is different when we have M>2 classes. Also theory says that we should follow a slightly different process than this for M>2 classes but I don't get it...

```
class1=load('class_1.dat');
class2=load('class_2.dat');
class3=load('class_3.dat');   

[m1_ML,S1_ML]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(class1');
[m2_ML,S2_ML]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(class2');
[m3_ML,S3_ML]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(class3');

m1_ML
S1_ML
m2_ML
S2_ML
m3_ML
S3_ML

for i=1:50
  for j=1:4
    CLASS(i,j)=class1(i,j);
    CLASS(i+50,j)=class2(i,j);
    CLASS(i+100,j)=class3(i,j);

  end
end

CLASS1=CLASS';

for i=1:50
    true_labels(i)=1;
    true_labels(i+50)=2;
    true_labels(i+100)=3;
end

classified=ones(1,150);

n=150;
for j = 1:n
  inds = true(n,1);
  inds(j) = false;

  X1= CLASS1(:,inds);
  Y1= CLASS1(:,~inds);

  TL1=true_labels(:,inds);
  TL2=true_labels(:,~inds);

  for i=1:4
     [m11(i),S11(i)]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(X1(i,find(TL1==1)));
  end

  for i=1:4
     [m22(i),S22(i)]=Gaussian_ML_estimate(X1(i,find(TL1==2)));
  end


  for i=1:4
     perFeature1(i,:)=normpdf(Y1(i,:),m11(i),sqrt(S11(i)));
     perFeature2(i,:)=normpdf(Y1(i,:),m22(i),sqrt(S22(i)));
  end

  naive_probs1=prod(perFeature1);
  naive_probs2=prod(perFeature2);

  if naive_probs1<naive_probs2
    classified(j)=2;
  end
end  
Naive_Error=sum(true_labels~=classified)/150
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the theory for us? I am a bit puzzled about how to devide multiple classes with a linear boundary. Are you trying a one-vs-rest approach?

Comment: [here](http://www.slideshare.net/karbakh/theodoridisskoutroumbaskpatternrecognition4edap2009) it is (page 117 of 967 - Multiclass Generalization)
I am using the leave-one-out approach